# POST image to server iOS not working

Tags: ios, http, post

I'm attempting to make a post request to a server in iOS on my ipad. I've followed and tried multiple examples posted, but I still can't get it working. The post request always responds with a 200 status code and an HTML page, but it should be responding with json according the API and the creator of the API. I've been given an example POST request that works. Below is the function I've been using to try to send a photo.

```
-(IBAction)testSendPhoto:(id)sender
{
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSMutableArray * currentFormPictures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.pictures[appDelegate.currentForm]];

NSString * pictureFilePath = currentFormPictures[0];
NSLog(@"Sending picture:%@", pictureFilePath);
NSString *filename =[pictureFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/"] withString:@""];
UIImage * pictureFile = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pictureFilePath];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pictureFile, 1.0f);

NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://urlForSite.com/?format=json"];
[urlString appendString:@"&username="];
[urlString appendString:appDelegate.username];
[urlString appendString:@"&api_key="];
[urlString appendString:appDelegate.apikey];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"Sending it to URL: %@", urlString);

NSMutableURLRequest * request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"Post Body:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postbody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
[postbody appendData:imageData];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
//NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postbody length]];
//[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Working example given by the API creator:

```
POST /warehouse/apiTempFileUploader/?format=json&username=admin&api_key=c67332f5596301f598c1807a6767a048ed1d17d9 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="GPSEXIF.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

i've also used

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
```

as the content type, but still no luck. I've also removed the header at the advice of the API creator with no luck

--Update with didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, and connectionDidFinishLoading

```
 (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSLog(@"Response from connection: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSDictionary * headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
statusCode = (int)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
NSLog(@"headers: %@", headers);
NSLog(@"Status code: %d", statusCode);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSString * responseJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error: nil];
NSLog(@"JSon: %@", JSON);
NSLog(@"response data - %@", responseJson);
}
```

Comment: I am sure the username and api key should be in the URL. I have other posts that are only text json bodies that work for other API calls with similar URLs.

Comment: I haven't implemented didFailWithError. I'll add my didReceiveData and connectionDidFinishLoading to my original question, they mostly consist of logging. I'll implement didFailWithError and see what I get back.

Comment: responseJson comes back as an html page of the template for a basic page for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest examining the request in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) to make sure the request looks like what it should. A couple of observations:

1. It is definitely `multipart/form-data`, not just `form-data`.
2. You said that instead of receiving JSON response, that you receive "html page of the template for a basic page for the site".

   It's very unusual for a page that should return JSON to return a HTML page. That can happen if there was some fundamental problem that prevented the API developer's code from running at all (e.g. a basic authentication error or the URL, itself, was incorrect). I bet if you tell your API developer what sort of HTML response you received, he/she can probably help you diagnose what went wrong.

Unrelated to your immediate challenge:

1. I would not suggest using a boundary that, itself, starts with dashes. I don't think it causes problems, but it just makes it confusing when you get into debugging the request in something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). Because your boundary includes four dashes, you're going to see six dashes in the request. It just seems unnecessarily confusing.
2. I'm surprised that `username` and `api_key` are part of the URL, as that is not secure. You assure us that you have confirmed that this is what the API design requires, but once you get this immediate issue behind you, you really should broach that topic with the API developer, as it's not prudent to put authentication details in a URL. The image data as well as and both `username` and `api_key` should get their own "part" in the body of the request, not appear in the URL itself.
3. You really don't want to round-trip `pictureFilePath` through a `UIImage`. Just use `dataWithContentsOfFile` and get the data directly, and just send that. `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` may well generate a payload that differs from the original image (and with factor of 1.0f, it may be larger than your original file, if less than `1.0f`, you can introduce some image degradation). Unless you have some explicit reason for round-tripping this through `UIImage`, you shouldn't.
4. If there is any chance that either user username or the api key could contain reserved characters (e.g. `+` or `&` or space), you really need to percent escape those values before adding them to your URL. And, note, do not use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, but rather use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`:

   ```
   /** Percent escape string
    *
    * Note, this does not use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, because
    * that that will not percent escape some critical reserved characters (notably
    * `&` and `+`). This uses `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, instead.
    */
   - (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
   {
       NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                    (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
       return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
   }
   ```

   This isn't necessary if the value is specified in a `multipart/form-data` request, but if in the URL or if in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, you need to percent escape.

Comment: After looking through my request in Charles and am starting to doubt that the API is working. I'm going to get in touch with the developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

Should be `@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@"`.

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

---

*UPDATE*

I see your new update. You **MUST** include the content type of `multipart/form-data`.

see [multipart/form-data](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) and [HTML5 Specification > Forms > multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data).

---

*UPDATE 2*

I'm not sure how much you changed the URLs, but in the code provided, you have no path.

```
NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://urlForSite.com/?format=json"];
```

Where as in the sample the path is `/warehouse/apiTempFileUploader/`.

Have you tried:

```
NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://urlForSite.com/warehouse/apiTempFileUploader/?format=json"];
```

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: I get a response of the HTML code of the basic page for the site. (menu bars and whatnot)

Comment: Apologies,
    NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://devSite.com/warehouse/apiTempFileUploader/?format=json"];
is the url I am using. I don't have permission to post the url at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might need to add

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

To tell the server you are accepting a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

The main part of your request should definitely be "multipart/form-data", not just "form-data".

Also, it would help if you add one more header in the part for the file. This header would be:
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

And one last observation, your code is almost perfect. The HTTP sample you have underneath is not right. Boundaries should have a "--" prefix at the start of each part and an additional "--" suffix at the end of the request.

I recently wrote an article just for what you are trying to do. [Check it out](http://www.creativepulse.gr/en/blog/2014/restful-api-requests-using-objective-c-works-on-ios-and-mac), it may help.

Comment: Can you be more specific on where I'm missing the "--". I have them before the first boundary and before and after the last boundary. I'm going to attempt from scratch using your examples in your article.

Comment: That is in the HTTP sample, under the phrase "Working example given by the API creator". The code has it right, the sample under the code is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll ask the dev about it.